# How to get visits per day via the API?

Tags: support, api, sites

At the overview page of the Stack Exchange network, one can see a [list of all sites of the network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) with some statistics for each site (number of questions, answers etc.). Most of these statistics can be calculated via the API, except the visits per day. At least I could not found a [site parameter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) to get the visits per day.

Did I overlook anything? Is there a way to get the number of visits per day for each site via the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, this information is not in [the API<sup>(Docs)</sup>](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), nor is there an easy way to compute it from data that is available.

[Nor can you get visit info from SEDE or the Data Dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede).

Your only recourse is to scrape [the sites page](https://stackexchange.com/sites) or to use third party providers like Quantcast or Google for traffic info.

Also note that the *visits/day* info on the sites page [is a lie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111882/how-can-we-have-a-31-day-old-site-with-14k-views-but-only-138-visits-day#comment331347_111889), designed to [inflate traffic numbers 90% of the time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180138/traffic-stats-use-median-and-not-mean).

Comment: Well, it's an estimate based on a median. If that's a lie then there's a large pack of liars over at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ hehe